# As soon pdf file is open in Internet Explorer, the printmask should be open

Tags: c#, pdf, internet-explorer, macros

Scenario:

1. Open Internet Explorer
2. Go to a specific web page
3. Type some required information
4. Click on button Information will be transferred
5. After that a pdf file will be created and shown in the Browser (IE new
   Tab)

Now what I need is, to print this pdf file automaticly or open the print mask and than press enter.

I expected to do this with macros, but no idea how to do that in IE.
A other idea is to write a service in C# to listen some events....

Has someone an idea?
Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You can try to refer the code example below and start to learn IE Automation using VBA. This is a good starting example for you. Try it on your side and let us know, If you meet with any problem.

```
Sub Automate_IE_Load_Page()
'This will load a webpage in IE
    Dim i As Long
    Dim URL As String
    Dim IE As Object
    Dim objElement As Object
    Dim objCollection As Object

    'Create InternetExplorer Object
    Set IE = CreateObject("InternetExplorer.Application")

    'Set IE.Visible = True to make IE visible, or False for IE to run in the background
    IE.Visible = True

    'Define URL
    URL = "https://www.Microsoft.com"

    'Navigate to URL
    IE.Navigate URL

    ' Statusbar let's user know website is loading
    Application.StatusBar = URL & " is loading. Please wait..."

    ' Wait while IE loading...
    'IE ReadyState = 4 signifies the webpage has loaded (the first loop is set to avoid inadvertently skipping over the second loop)
    Do While IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do While
    Do Until IE.ReadyState = 4: DoEvents: Loop   'Do Until

    'Webpage Loaded
    Application.StatusBar = URL & " Loaded"

    'Unload IE
    Set IE = Nothing
    Set objElement = Nothing
    Set objCollection = Nothing

End Sub
```

Reference:

[Automate Internet Explorer (IE) Using VBA](https://www.automateexcel.com/vba/automate-internet-explorer-ie-using/)

To print from IE, You can refer the answer in link below.

[Print an IE Web Page](https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/office/en-US/d42e8dee-4407-4dab-bacc-18f90e169b89/print-an-ie-web-page?forum=exceldev)